# Stylesheet not loaded on register page

Tags: wp-enqueue-style

Using WordPress 4.2.2. Im trying to add some custom fields to the registration page. I have gotten the fields to show up there now, but for some reason i cannot get the stylesheet to load there too. The stylesheet loads fine on all other pages it seems but not the register page.

Im using this to load the scripts

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', array(&$this, "enqueueScripsAndStyles"));
public function enqueueScripsAndStyles() {
    //Styles
    wp_enqueue_style('sh_billing_styling', plugins_url('/css/sh_billing.css', __FILE__));
    wp_enqueue_style('sh_billing_fontawesome', plugins_url('/css/font-awesome.min.css', __FILE__));
    //Scripts
    wp_enqueue_script('sh_billing_radiobuttons', plugins_url('/js/custom-form-elements.js', __FILE__));
}
```

Am i missing something? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `login_enqueue_scripts` for the login page.

See: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/login_enqueue_scripts

Swap that out in your `add_action`, or add a new one, and it should work.